# Extract values from a string using regex

Tags: regex

**String** - try the Club for 1 Dollar

I am trying to get 3 values from the string :

**quantity** - try the

**metal** - Club

**value** - Dollar

but I am getting **lub** for **metal**.
Regex I tried :

```
(?<quantity>[\s\S]*?)[A-Z](?<metal>[\S]*?)\sfor\s(?<value>[\d]+?)\sDollar
```

I am not able to correct the regex. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: Thanks for the edit...I am not sure what flavor means..I am using it in C# if that helps

Comment: @sln Thanks a lot . It worked perfectly.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer in case anybody will use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `[A-Z]` is matching C. Change it to `(?=[A-Z])`

`(?<quantity>[\s\S]*?)(?=[A-Z])(?<metal>[\S]*?)\sfor\s(?<value>[\d]+?)\sDollar`

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0            -  ( pos 0 , len 25 ) 
try the Club for 1 Dollar  
 **  Grp 1 [quantity] -  ( pos 0 , len 8 ) 
try the   
 **  Grp 2 [metal]    -  ( pos 8 , len 4 ) 
Club  
 **  Grp 3 [value]    -  ( pos 17 , len 1 ) 
1
```